# Can it convert to specific type?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, constructor

I have to send parameter to a constructor of  a new class. the parameter i sent is generic. inside the constructor I have to use a field of it (id). but i cannot use it directly, then i want to cast it before using. but It said cannot convert type T to my specific type.

for example

```
    public class Pet<T>
    {
        foodType foodType; // enum
        public Pet(T sample)
        {
           if(sample.GetType() == typeof(Dog)
           {
              var pet = (Dog)pet; // there is an error.
              foodType = FoodType.Milk;
           } 
           if(sample.GetType() == typeof(Cat)
           {
              var pet = (Cat)pet; // there is an error.
              foodType = FoodType.Fish;
           }     
        }

    }
```

how to cast it? or it has no way to do.

I have edit the sample code. Is it better?

Comment: Your design is horribly flawed. Can you give us a proper example? Or is this it?

Comment: Well what do you expect the cast to do? What will the actual value be? If it's not a `Dog`, how do you expect the conversion to happen? And do you even *have* a non-generic `Dog` type to cast it to? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Is there a class you declared like `Dog`? It should be `Dog<Something>` and that also makes no sense

Comment: Do you really need generics? Seems like base class or interface could work fine. Speaking of your code sample which is really unclear to say exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off explaining what you're aiming to achieve, in specific terms. I don't think the design above can express what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've heard about `Dog<byte>` or `Dog<float>`, but can't imagine what a `Dog<DateTime>` would be like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'where' word. Like this:

```
public class Dog<T> where T: IHasId
```

This means that T must be inherited from IHasId interfase

Comment: But still will he be able to get id, when using this solution?

Comment: Yes, if it presents in IHasId interfase

Comment: @ant _Type constraint_ would be more correct term. Also I guess OP does not need generic at all. :)

Comment: @Leri apparently he doesn't but when I suggested this in my answer got downvoted three times, so I would not suggest it.

Comment: Thank you, I use this way with where T : baseclass

Comment: @groupgrip Why won't you pass `BaseClass` directly?

Comment: @Leri How to do that? Actually at first, I have to create 2 constructors to received value foe type Fish and Dog, then I thought I should to use generic.

Comment: @groupgrip No. Create a constructor, which takes argument of type `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point of generics. You can solve this problem far better without generics:

```
public interface IPetFoodChoice
{
    FoodType preferedFoodType { get; }
}

public class Dog : IPetFoodChoice
{
    public FoodType preferedFoodType { get { return FoodType.Milk; } }
}

public class Cat : IPetFoodChoice
{
    public FoodType preferedFoodType { get { return FoodType.Fish; } }
}

public class Pet
{
    private FoodType _foodType;

    public Pet(IPetFoodChoice sample)
    {
        _foodType = sample.preferedFoodType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was about to post almost the same. Just one note OP might want to have getter for passed object.